# JSON data stopped returning after moving to live server

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a small app fetching teams from MySQL DB. It works perfectly on localhost, but after moving to live server it does not return anything and does not error out either.

I imported the DB from localhost, changed DB details in functions.php as I moved live. I know that connection with new DB is established properly.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ikushlia_ilya', 'kalmar12', 'ikushlia_uefa_teams');
// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (isset($_GET['selectAllUEFAClubs'])) {
  $selectAllUEFAClubs = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM clubs");
    if ($selectAllUEFAClubs->num_rows > 0) {
    $allTeamsFetched = array();
      while($row = $selectAllUEFAClubs->fetch_assoc()) {
        $team = ["club_name" => $row['club_name'], "club_country" => $row['club_country'], "club_ranking" => $row['club_ranking'], "club_logo_url" => $row['club_logo'], "league_place" => $row['league_place']];
        array_push($allTeamsFetched,$team);
      }
      echo json_encode($allTeamsFetched);
    }
}
```

and JS with AJAX call:

```
var championsLeague = {
  potentialTeams: [],
  getAllTeams(){
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'functions.php?selectAllUEFAClubs',
      type: 'GET'
    });
  }
};
function prepareTeamsForDraw(){
  championsLeague.getAllTeams().done(function(result){
  $.each(result, function(key, value){
    championsLeague.potentialTeams.push(value);
  });
  // do something with the array
 }
 prepareTeamsForDraw();
```

Status code is 200 OK, content-Type is application/json. Everything seems to be working, but no data is returned.

My localhost is Apache and Hostgator's server is nginx though I think this is not the issue.

**EDIT 1:**
Added an error and success callback to my AJAX call.

```
getAllTeams(){
return $.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'functions.php?selectAllUEFAClubs',
  type: 'GET',
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    throw new Error('your error is ' + error);
  }, 
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('ajax call successful');
  }
});
}
```

**It logs out the following**: your error is SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: Try this one `array_push($allTeamsFetched,$team);`

Comment: unfortunately, it had no effect...

Comment: I think that allTeamsFetched contains only the last row that's why you rather chose `array_push` instead, am I right?

Comment: I am on a live server already, so I need to find a way to enable error reporting on hostgator. I suspect there is an issue with PHP versions, because on localhost I had php7 and hostgator's version may be ph5

Comment: Selim Ajimi, I mean I tried your suggestion now but nothing's changed

Comment: Try adding a value to the GET parameter in the AJAX call. `url: 'functions.php?selectAllUEFAClubs=true',`. Maybe the variable is not set if it doesn't have a value. Also: Is your DB on the webserver populated? Maybe you just get 0 results. You could add some error handling in `else` clauses, like ` die('{ "error": "selectAllUEFAClubs not set" }')` and see what you get from that.

Comment: DB is populated with 154 entries. I have an HTML page and upon clicking a button I fire an AJAX request to the PHP file. I don't know whether PHP error reporting works if only an AJAX request is issued.